# Iterator to LONG_PTR

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

would I be able to cast iterator that is pointing to a set element to a LONG_PTR?

PS: I don't fully understand what is LONG_PTR?

Here is an example code which pops an error at runtime

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void func(LPARAM lp)
{
    set<string>::iterator *it = reinterpret_cast<set<string>::iterator*>(lp);

    string s = *(*it); //runtime-error
}

int main()
{
    char *arr[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

    set<string> s(arr, arr+5);
    set<string>::iterator it = s.begin()++;

    LONG_PTR lp = reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&*it);

    func(lp);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `LONGPTR` is an [`__int3264`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367390%28VS.85%29.aspx).

In any case, you can't cast an iterator to this type because an iterator is not a pointer.  You can, however, take the address of the element pointed to by the iterator (using `&*it`), assuming the type of object stored in the container does not overload the unary `&` (if it does overload the unary `&`, it's a bad, bad class).

Comment: @James: I'm curious (as I'm still pretty new to C++), have you encountered a legitimate use for an overloaded `&` operator?

Comment: @dreamlax: No; I've not seen any legitimate use of that. I'm sure it is overloaded somewhere in Boost with some awesome results.  There was one interesting use that AndreyT posted a few months back.  Basically, you can overload the unary `&` to be able to obtain the address of a temporary object.  I don't think that that is legitimate, but it is interesting.

Comment: @ James: would you correct me if I'm wrong `LONG_PTR lp = reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&*it);`  it is iterator to set element.

Comment: @ James I've posted the situation.

Comment: @dfx: `&*it` isn't the iterator. As James said, it's a pointer to the same element referred to by the iterator. Iterators overload unary `operator*`, so for them it is *not* simply the inverse of unary `operator&`.

Comment: @dfx:  What @Steve said.  You need to cast to a `string*`, not a `set<string>::iterator*`.

Comment: @James: That worked thanks, what should need to know to understand what steve has just said?

Comment: I got it now, I was confusing the iterator with pointer to element. Thanks again guys! @James I'd like to know if jamesmcnellis.com works?

Comment: @dfx:  I don't understand... what do you need to know?  Iterators overload various operators, including the unary `*`.  Are you familiar with operator overloading?  (If not, consult your favorite C++ book.)  As for the domain; there isn't anything there.  It's only used for e-mail.

Comment: @James would it be possible to customize the iterator class I mean manipulating an iterator's returns values and what goes on inside of it including overloading stuff? I have seen someone wrote his own iterator class for set container.

Answer (score 0):

Probably no, if you mean `std::set` by set. Generally, STL iterators are objects much more complex than a pointer.

LONG_PTR is a type big enough to hold either a long, or a pointer.